# Mark end of the row when using match() javascript

Tags: javascript, string, match

How to mark end of the row when using match() function?
From this page I need to pull out "2021 JANUARY 18 MONDAY"

[image: webpage look]

[image: sourcecode]

When somethng exists after desired string I've used this code:

```
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getContentText();

var date = page.match(/results of (.*?)SOMETHING/m)[1];
```

but now I can't

Comment: So the pattern is Year Month day dayname?

Comment: Yes, that's the pattern of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how that date format can be matched in a string:

```js
var string = "lorem ipsum 2021 January 18 Monday";
var date = string.match(/(\d{4} [A-z]+ \d{1,2} [A-z]+)/)[0] || null;

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

To match the date at the end of the row, you could use the `$` anchor and make the format for the date like pattern a bit more specific.

Note that `[A-z]` [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than `[A-Za-z]`. To make the pattern case insensitive you could use the `/i` flag.

```
^.* ((?:19|20)\d{2} [A-Z]+ (?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) [A-Z]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EHTtNW/1)

- `^` Start of string
- `.*`  Match 0+ times any char till the last space
- `(` Capture **group 1** *(This contains the date like value)*

  - `(?:19|20)\d{2}`  Match a year 19 or 20 followed by 2 digits and a space
  - `[A-Z]+`  Match 1+ times an uppercase char A-Z followed by a space
  - `(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])`  Match a day 1 - 31
  - `[A-Z]+`  Match 1+ times an uppercase char A-Z followed by a space
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

```js
var page = "NHL 2020-2021 ratings through results of 2021 JANUARY 18 MONDAY";
var date = page.match(/^.* ((?:19|20)\d{2} [A-Z]+ (?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) [A-Z]+$)/i)
if (date)
  console.log(date[1]);
```